# Syntax Error exec-ing python code from database

Tags: python, exec

I'm loading some python code from a database (it's doing dynamic mapping of values that I can change at runtime without a code redeploy).

In my code, I'm doing this to execute the database code:

```
if lMapping:
  print lMapping
  exec lMapping
  lValue = mapping(lValue, lCsvRow)
```

and here's the value of lMapping:

```
def mapping(pValue, pCsvRow):
  lInterimStatus = pCsvRow[5]
  lOutComeStatus = pCsvRow[6]

  if len(lInterimStatus) == 0:
    lStatus = lOutComeStatus
  else:
    lStatus = lInterimStatus

  lStatus = lStatus.lower()

  PRIMARY_STATUS_MAPPINGS = {
    'completed with lender' : '4828',
    'not taken up' : '4827',
    'declined across all lenders' : '4726',
    'declined broker duplicate' : '4726',
    'pending' : '4725',
    'pending (in progress with broker)' : '4725',
    'pending (in progress with lender)' : '4725',
    'lender accept in principle' : '4827',
    'lender decline duplicate' : '4743',
    'lender decline post code not supported' : '4743',
    'lender decline score fail' : '4743',
    'lender decline policy fail' : '4743',
    'lender decline no client contact' : '4743',
    'lender decline general' : '4743',
    'lender decline bad data' : '4743',
  }

  return PRIMARY_STATUS_MAPPINGS[lStatus]
```

Whenever I do this I'm getting a syntax error on the exec line, I can't work out why:

`(<type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>:invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)`

#### UPDATE

It works if I write the code from the database to a file first:

```
print lMapping
lFile = open('/mapping.py','w')
lFile.write(lMapping)
lFile.close()
lReadFile = open('/mapping.py')
exec lReadFile
lValue = mapping(lValue, lCsvRow)
```

Comment: copying this string to my python interactive and executing your code doen't seems to be broken. Maybe you have some other problem somewhere in other place.

Comment: This looks like a bad design to me. It's better to use python pickle to store the values. Then store the pickle in the database or in a file.

Comment: Could you post a `repr(lMapping)` before storing to database and after retrieving from it?

Comment: Things to consider:  1. try "print repr(lMapping)" instead and examine that, or show us,  and 2. show us the full traceback.  What you've shown doesn't appear to be a normal traceback, so you've got other code involved.  I think the suggestion that you have wrong line-endings is probably correct.  Maybe '\n'.join(lMapping.splitlines()) would be a good step to try.

Comment: Why is it bad design not to pickle to store a bit of text?  surely that limits the front ends that can be used to edit the database - I couldn't edit the script from TOAD/sql*plus for example?

Comment: If you want to edit the values in the database then use JSON format instead of pickle. The advantage is that you can easily use those values else where because they are not Python specific. You don't have to worry about line endings issues. spaces/tabs inconsistencies or syntax errors.

Comment: ...but the values in the database are python code.  The example above is only one possible mapping, others might simply upper case the value passed in and return it.  Rather than develop a DSL I've put python in the database.  This particular mapping is quite complex in that it needs to look at two different fields (from a third party CSV file) to work out what to return.  Others will take one value and return it.  Using code gives much more flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you BLOB or other *binary* type column to store code? Otherwise database might change line endings and exec will break with `SyntaxError`:

```
>>> s='''\
... print 'ok'
... '''
>>> s
"print 'ok'\n"
>>> exec s
ok
>>> exec s.replace('\n', '\r\n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    print 'ok'
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Update**: Writing to file on Windows in text mode will change line endings to platform native ones. Another way to normalize them is:

```
lMapping = os.linesep.join(lMapping.splitlines())
```

Comment: The table was created by django, NVARCHAR2(2000).  It's an oracle database.

Comment: It's down to the line ends as you suggested, but your solution would only work where os.linesep was '\n'. I'm developing on windows and deploying on solaris, so I fixed it by doing lMapping = lMapping.replace('\r\n','\n').  Thanks.